# IIS 10 - Missing Managed Handlers Types

Tags: windows-server-2016, iis-10, reinstall

Recently we upgraded one of our internal servers from Windows Server 2012 R2 to 2016. There were some missing configurations in IIS and I had to reinstall extensions like Web Platform Installer, URLRewrite etc.

This upgrade also broke our .NET Core 3 hosted website and upon some investigation I found that handler configuration seems to be missing in IIS. I need help restoring the handlers.

[image: Missing Managed Handlers Types]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Input your type name manually. Sometimes it could not load type names in dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following steps to solve the problem：

- run the aspnet_regiis -ir

For x86, run `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir.`

For x64, run `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir`.

Or

- click Revert to Parent in the right nav of IIS in the Handler
  Mappings section.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work the IIS was already "registered" at least according to IIS but not at the OS level because the Windows folder got substituted.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled .NET 4.8, .NET 3.1 Core one more time to get it work. Restarted a few times in between. Not sure which one did the trick exactly though!

Thank you all for your help!